# How to do a 'groupby' by multilevel index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'RPT' indexed by (STK_ID,RPT_Date), contains the accumulated sales of stocks for each qurter:

```
                       sales
STK_ID  RPT_Date
000876  20060331      798627000
        20060630     1656110000
        20060930     2719700000
        20061231     3573660000
        20070331      878415000
        20070630     2024660000
        20070930     3352630000
        20071231     4791770000
600141  20060331      270912000
        20060630      658981000
        20060930     1010270000
        20061231     1591500000
        20070331      319602000
        20070630      790670000
        20070930     1250530000
        20071231     1711240000
```

I want to calculate the single qurterly sales using 'groupby' by STK_ID & RPT_Yr ,such as : `RPT.groupby('STK_ID','RPT_Yr')['sales'].transform(lambda x: x-x.shift(1))` , how to do that ?

suppose I can get the year by `lambda x : datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d').year`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming here that RPT_Data is a string, any reason why not to use Datetime?

It is possible to groupby using functions, but only on a non MultiIndex-index. Working around this by resetting the index, and set 'RPT_Date' as index to extract the year (note: pandas toggles between object and int as dtype for 'RPT_Date').

```
In [135]: year = lambda x : datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y%m%d').year

In [136]: grouped = RPT.reset_index().set_index('RPT_Date').groupby(['STK_ID', year])

In [137]: for key, df in grouped:
   .....:     print key
   .....:     print df
   .....:
(876, 2006)
          STK_ID       sales
RPT_Date
20060331     876   798627000
20060630     876  1656110000
20060930     876  2719700000
20061231     876  3573660000
(876, 2007)
          STK_ID       sales
RPT_Date
20070331     876   878415000
20070630     876  2024660000
20070930     876  3352630000
20071231     876  4791770000
(600141, 2006)
          STK_ID       sales
RPT_Date
20060331  600141   270912000
20060630  600141   658981000
20060930  600141  1010270000
20061231  600141  1591500000
(600141, 2007)
          STK_ID       sales
RPT_Date
20070331  600141   319602000
20070630  600141   790670000
20070930  600141  1250530000
20071231  600141  1711240000
```

Other option is to use a tmp column

```
In [153]: RPT_tmp = RPT.reset_index()

In [154]: RPT_tmp['year'] = RPT_tmp['RPT_Date'].apply(year)

In [155]: grouped = RPT_tmp.groupby(['STK_ID', 'year'])
```

**EDIT**
Reorganising your frame make it much easier.

```
In [48]: RPT
Out[48]: 
                                  sales
STK_ID RPT_Year RPT_Quarter            
876    2006     0             798627000
                1            1656110000
                2            2719700000
                3            3573660000
       2007     0             878415000
                1            2024660000
                2            3352630000
                3            4791770000
600141 2006     0             270912000
                1             658981000
                2            1010270000
                3            1591500000
       2007     0             319602000
                1             790670000
                2            1250530000
                3            1711240000

In [49]: RPT.groupby(level=['STK_ID', 'RPT_Year'])['sales'].apply(sale_per_q)
Out[49]: 
STK_ID  RPT_Year  RPT_Quarter
876     2006      0               798627000
                  1               857483000
                  2              1063590000
                  3               853960000
        2007      0               878415000
                  1              1146245000
                  2              1327970000
                  3              1439140000
600141  2006      0               270912000
                  1               388069000
                  2               351289000
                  3               581230000
        2007      0               319602000
                  1               471068000
                  2               459860000
                  3               460710000
```

Comment: It is quite tricky and the code is ugly. Is there any pythonic or pandasnic way to do so ?

Comment: def sale_per_q(s):
    sq = s.diff()
    sq[s.index[0]] = s.iget(0)
    return sq

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RPT['sales'].groupby([RPT['STK_ID'],RPT['RPT_Yr']]).sum()
```

^^ you need to reference the indices within a list. this worked for me